# Asyncronously send messages to third party systems - queue?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, notifications, queue

We have an ASP.NET MVC web app which allows users to publish messages onto a web site. Alongside this, the user is also able to syndicate that message content to other 3rd party systems when they post the message.

At present, this is done synchronously, so when they click the 'Post' button, we persist their message to the database and then notify each 3rd party systems in turn. We need to improve the scalability and durability of this operation so I would like to make the notification aspect of the action asynchronous in some way.

I can think of the following possiblities

- Save the 3rd party messages into a database table and have some worker process read items from the table and post to the 3rd party systems.
- Use a "proper" message queue of some sort like nServiceBus or RabbitMQ (I have no experience with either of these)

Is there a better way to do this? I'm particularly interested in how to notify the user that the message has been syndicated correctly (since it's ansynchronous) and also how to handle multiple retry failures, at which point the sender should just give up.

Thanks

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NServiceBus is a great framework for implementing asynchronous communication. If you use it for this use case, you will see many other opportunities for applying messaging for improving the scalability and reliability of your system.

Create a MessagePosted event message that is published after a message is persisted to the database. For each third party system that might be notified of the message, create an event handler class that implements IHandleMessages.

Multiple retry failures is facilitated by NServiceBus, just throw an exception within the event handler if something goes wrong. The event will be resubmitted to the event handler for a configurable number of retries before the event is moved to the error queue.

To notify the user you can for instance create a status view or widget which shows the notification results of the latest messages. If a third party system cannot be notified you can consider sending the user an e-mail so that he can take action.

Use this publish subscribe sample to get up to speed quickly: http://docs.particular.net/samples/pubsub/

Answer (score 0):

You should read this: It explains how to use pub sub with RabbitMQ http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html